# How do I use both hard and soft water when I have a water softener installed?

Tags: water, faucet, water-softener

I moved into a house constructed in year 2000 that already has an Ionics Hydro 5000 water softener installed. The old owner never left a manual and I couldn't find a manual online, so I'll voice my concerns here.

The water softener is installed in the garage, which is in the front of the house:

[image]

On the adjacent wall in the front of the house, I see two spigots. I suppose one is for softened water and one is for the original hard water. I should be using the hard water spigot to wash my car so I can reserve the soft water for indoor use. How do I know which one is which?

[image]

In the back of the house, I have a single spigot. Is it serving hard or soft water? In the back yard I have fruit trees that need watering. The salt in the soft water will dehydrate trees, so it is cruicial that I don't use soft water on them.

[image]

As requested by @TDHofstetter, this is a closeup of the shutoff valves going into the head of the water softener:

[image]

Comment: If it's got a lot of mineral content, hard water leaves mineral spots on paint and glass, I'd recommend going to the local car wash and using their deionized water rinse feature for best life span on your car paint job. Just an idea from experience as the mineral rings that accumulate on glass are easy to prevent that way and hard to remove.

Comment: Before I turned on the softener, I never noticed any white residue on my car, dishes, sinks, etc... But I started getting severe acne after moving in to the house, so I thought if experiment to see if turning on the softener would help. The downfall is that I don't want to kill my plants by watering with salty soft water.

Comment: I haven't heard of mineral content causing acne and it sounds like the water is reasonably low mineral if it's not spotting stuff. However I would have the water checked for industrial contaminants and other halogenated organic compounds as they cause a condition called chloroacne.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I looked up photos of chloroacne and I don't look like all bumpy like that. Mine just looks like regular teenage acne. When I searched for "had water acne" on Google, it returned a lot of articles supporting the correlation. Here is my [city's 2013 water quality report](http://www.sjwater.com/files/documents/SJWC_Water_Quality.pdf/). I don't know how all those listed chemicals affect health. I don't drink the tap water though - I filter with a [Pur water pitcher](http://www.purwater.com/).

Comment: @jojo3, softened water shouldn't be salty. If it is, something's wrong with the process or machine

Comment: @alt All the articles on my Google search of "[softened water plants](https://www.google.com/search?q=softened+water+plants&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)" indicate that softened water has sodium (Na). I'm not sure if Na by itself is salty. I know salt (NaCl) is obviously salty. But in any case, the articles say that Na fools plants into thinking that they're hydrated, when in fact they are not. Softened water is also void of calcium and magnesium, which plants need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that water softener has a shutoff valve (it should, for service purposes), your task is simple - shut off the softener and test each sillcock. If you still get water, it's hard water. If not, you may get a very small flow for a moment (until the plumbing is all depressurized) but it'll stop quickly.

If it does NOT have a shutoff valve, one should really be installed at some point, along with a pair of unions to make water-softener replacement or service easier.

Comment: I see two knobs where there are two pipes entering the top of the water softener. These knobs are parallel with the tubes, which I assume means the flow is unrestricted. However, unlike the knobs which I've seen in people's YouTube videos, my knobs are plastic and aren't turnable. They look turnable, but I couldn't.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the knobs? They may be something we'll recognize as valves or as something else.

Comment: Here's the photo of the knobs: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BvLYOGsCcAAReKR.jpg:large . Other people's shutoff valves look like handles that you can wrap your whole hand around. Mine look like you just use your fingers, but they don't even turn...

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a pair of bypass/shutoff valves. The lower one in the photo is hard water inlet from the source, the upper is soft water outlet to the house. If you can get ONE (but NOT BOTH) of those valves to turn until the top bar is perpendicular to its current position, that should shut off soft water completely to the house. DO NOT turn them BOTH, that will just bypass the water softener completely. It looks like those knobs should turn clockwise from their current position.

Comment: FFR, the two knurled knobs around the pipes serve as service unions, and the small grey knob below them appears to be a bleeder.

Comment: On the days I need to water my plants, I'll need to make sure the spigot in the backyard is serving hard water. Can you explain how turning both knobs would accomplish this? It seems like the water softener is the middleman between the hard water and the house. `Hard -> Softener -> House`. If I take the softener out of the equation, what's going to link the hard water to the house? From what I'm seeing superficially, the link would be severed. Could there be some internal pipes diverting the water flow?

Comment: I just tried to rotate the valves. They don't budge. I don't know how it's even mechanically possible - it's one solid piece of plastic.

Comment: Inside that valve body, under those two valves, is a bypass channel. If BOTH valves are turned, water will flow from the inlet side through the bypass channel directly to the outlet side & out to the house, so during that time the whole house will get hard water.

Comment: SURELY there's a small seam just under each of those knobs... but it's pretty moot if you're finding it impossible to turn them. Since they seem to be frozen in place (or the whole thing is just a casting made to LOOK like it has valves, or whatever), it'd be a good idea for you to install a pair of good brass globe valves into the copper lines just below the plastic valve body. Then you'll have full control, and you won't have to struggle with those plastic valves.

Comment: Yes! I was able to turn the knobs with a wrench! Now I can bypass it when watering my backyard fruit trees. I still don't know whether the backyard spigot is serving hard or soft water, but by bypassing I can be safe rather than sorry. So... how many pipes usually go from the city supply to a house? If it's just one, then doesn't that mean my backyard spigot is serving soft water? And if it's two, then there is a chance the backyard spigot wouldn't be using the water softener as a middleman. That's what my intuition tells me.

Comment: There would be only one line serving your house from the street, unless you have some very unusual circumstances in your neighborhood. Possibly a private well pump for lawn purposes? Usually, the city will install only one meter at the street, and your house will be connected to it with only one line. Hey, GOOD news you could turn that valve! It'll probably free up a little with more "exercise".

Comment: That rear hose bibb... MIGHT POSSIBLY be tapped into the city supply in some place where you can't see it, if you can't track its plumbing across the basement to a known pipe.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your second photo, I'd say that the top spigot is soft and the bottom is hard. The bottom is directly connected to the water main, coming up through the concrete, through the pressure regulator (the bell-shaped object) and thus, is connected before the softener.

There is no way to tell from the photos what is coming from the back-yard spigot. <strike>Your best bet is to buy a water hardness tester or test kit. I just did a search and currently, you can buy a tester from Amazon for around US$16.</strike> If your tap water is hard enough to warrant a softener, it is easy to test if water is direct tap or softened. Try washing your hands with standard hand soap. You should be able to tell the difference after rinsing: if your hands feel slippery, the water is softened. Try this first in the front where you have both so you can tell the difference.

If you decide not to use the softener, there may be a bypass valve on the back of the head of the unit, where the pipes enter.

Comment: Searching "[hard water test](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hard%20water%20test)" on Amazon turned up results for water testers that aren't specifically labeled as *hard* water testers. Would I be able to use this [affordable and reusable probe](http://www.amazon.com/HM-Digital-TDS-EZ-Measurement-Resolution/dp/B002C0A7ZY/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1408209256&sr=8-4&keywords=hard+water+test)? I really only care about my backyard fruit trees - I don't want salt getting into the soil. I couldn't care less if my car got washed with the wrong water.

Comment: Please see my edit.